# onmousedown, ondmouseup, onclick, ondblclick, oncontextmenu in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I work in html canvas and i need to do 4 actions:

- drag&drop elements
- stretch elements
- creat elemnts
- edit elemnts

So for:

- drag&drop: i should use canvas.onmousedown and canvas.ondmouseup
- stretch: canvas.onclick to select element then canvas.onclick on the frame of the element
- creat: canvas.ondblclick
- editing: canvas.oncontextmenu

but onmousedown and ondmouseup "override" all other clic.
and onclic "override" ondblclick

i tried:

```
canvas.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
        myContextmenu(canvas);   
       return false;
    }
```

and

```
canvas.addEventListener('ontextmenu', function(e) {
     alert("right clic"+e.clientX+";"+e.clientY);
   }, true);
```

one like the other doesn't work if i try with onmousedown, ondmouseup, onclick fonction.

If someone could help me welcome

Comment: http://georgealways.github.com/gee/ 
 - your welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to manage yourself click and double click detection using the onmousedown and onmouseup.

A click is a onmouseup following a onmousedown with almost no move between both.

A doubleclick is of course a fast succession of click.

So you have to store a few state variables, like the position and date of the mousedown (which is useful in dragging so you can compute the move at any time).

If you do manually the drag & drop (that is without using the not so compatible HTML5 new feature) you'll have tohook onmousemove so that you can display the dragged object during move (and it helps detecting move between down and up).